# Job interview who has no time

Tags: interviewing

I went to this interview and less then 2 minutes into the interview she says she has to rush through the interview as she has a meeting to go to.  Is she just giving me an excuse for ending the interview or do you think she REALLY has meeting to go to?

2 minutes is hardly enough time to decide if someone is suitable / unsuitable for a job position.

Comment: Why don't you ask her? What makes you think that we know what's on her mind?

Comment: Should have offered to reschedule

Comment: a 2-minute interview is a really bad sign. I would assume that they aren't interested.

Comment: Was it a government job?

Comment: They're not in any way obligated to interview you or give you any fixed amount of time. There could be any number of reasons for them passing on you or it could be they are in a jam and needed a emergency meeting. Whatever the case, give it three days then send them a friendly email to see if they're really interested or if it is time to move on.

Comment: One would think she'd schedule her meetings so they don't clash... Although admittedly an emergency could have come up, but then she should have made her apologies and offered to reschedule.

Comment: How were you dressed? Anything that's not "business friendly" perhaps? Do you have overt tattoos or piercings? Makeup (for a man)? Did you have strong cologne? Did you need cologne? Are you much older or much younger than the usual? Are you trans? Not saying any of these are justified, but certainly possibilities. It could be that she is required to interview a certain number of people but already knows who she is hiring but has to meet the arbitrary requirement. The possibilities are many and it's highly unlikely you'll ever find out.  Move on.

Comment: Was it "we're 2 minutes in, I have to leave NOW" or was it "we're 2 minutes in, and I'm letting you know that I might be more direct and push the process along at a non-leisurely pace" ?

Answer (score 6):

Either she is completely incompetent, which is unlikely... Or she's being excessively polite in not telling you that you aren't what she's looking for... Or the whole interview was a sham and they were wasting your time while establishing an excuse to hire the person they already selected ... Or she realized too late that some other department should have been interviewing you and didn't know how to fix that.

Whichever it is, the assumption should be that she isn't interested. Unless you get an inquiry from someone else in the company -- preferably with an apology for wasting your time once before -- I would write them off and continue looking elsewhere.

It isn't worth getting angry about this. That just wastes more of your time and energy.

Comment: Even if the employer is completely in the wrong in every sense, what do you expect to do?  Sue them until they give you a job?  Just move on to another employer.

Answer (score 3):

> Is she just giving me an excuse for ending the interview or do you think she REALLY has meeting to go to?

Does it matter? Even if she really did have a meeting to go to, that's some extraordinarily poor scheduling and it reflects so badly on the company that I would recommend turning down another interview if they try to reschedule.